# CAPTCHA Alternatives: What can spambots do?

Tags: security, captcha, spam

After deciding not to use CAPTCHA for my site, I added an [input=range] to my register page in place of a submit button that must be slid to the maximum value to submit. Will a spambot be able to bypass this measure? If so, are there any other good alternatives?

Comment: spambots can bypass anything they're programmed to recognize, which means whatever's being protected is worth enough that the bot's herders think it's worthwhile to beat your system. so... if you run a dinky no-one-will-ever-care service, then likely it's secure. if  what you've building turns out to be a Google-killer, then a slider isn't going to be much protect for more than a few microseconds.

Comment: The main problem is that human workforce is so cheap in some countries, that you will be dealing not with spambots themselves, but with human-driven captcha recognition. In this case you need to think how to make your site not attractive to spambots (while attractive to legitimate people).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spambots in general can beat anything that requires submitting a value to the server that can be determined by examining the code.  The key is to require the value to be something that a human can recognize easily but a bot could not.

For example, with your slide idea (not bad by the way), rather than having them slide it to the maximum (which would be easy for a bot to imitate), show them 3 pictures and ask them to slide it to the one that "makes them cold."  Then show a picture of an arctic wasteland, the sahara desert, and a furnace (this is just an example of course).  Those are the most spambot resistant controls.

The things you'll have to watch out for is predictability and repeatability.  If you always ask the same question, or if you only have a few different questions, it will be easy for attackers to enumerate all the possible results into an attack script and beat your control.

The only limit is really your creativity and a requirement to be difficult for code, easy for humans.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what the result of the physical sliding is in terms of code.  I have seen a JavaScript implementation of this (not sure if it's the same one) and it offers no security at all because all it does is send a request with a pre-determined token once the slide is complete.  However, there is nothing to stop a spam bot from simply acquiring the token on the page and sending the request to the server, which has no idea how the "user" got the token.

In the case of CAPTCHAs, the "token" is difficult for bots to decipher at this stage, but relatively easy for humans.

I personally can't stand any of these kinds of bot prevention measures, and I think most users would agree.  The only way to stop bots is to stop users too.

Comment: I can only select one answer, but thank you for the feedback! The slide is some code I made, just simple jQuery to check if the input=range has been slid to the correct value, not too much of a hinderance to a custom spambot, but whatever, I don't plan on getting too much traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Even if spambots can bypass captcha, human captcha solvers can bypass it. There's no perfect solution for spam. 
You can read about this issue here: http://blog.minteye.com/2013/02/26/captcha-solving-human-labor/